# Использование arraylist при больших объемах данных

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Здравствуйте, существует файлы с числовыми данными. Число строк в каждом файле разное.

Примерная структура.

2015        3        1        0        7       20      796,00       27        1

2015        3        1        0        7       20      796,00       27        1

2015        3        1        0        7       20      796,00       27        1

Нужно считать данные файлы и занести в массив для проведения расчетов. Проблема состоит в том, что изначально неизвестно из скольких строк будет состоять большой массив. Поэтому реализовал двойной arraylist.

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> massivData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
```

Данный подход работает эффективно только для массива небольшой длины. Однако когда мне нужно прочитать к примеру 100 файлов( каждый из которых в среднем имеет по 50000 строк) java просто напросто перегружает оперативную память. Если же работать со статичным массивом скорость работы вполне приемлемая.

Не знаю, как лучше реализовать объединение данных всех файлов в один массив. Как вариант, думаю при чтении файлов создать условный файл mergerfile, в который будет дозаписываться данные из каждого файла. Массив же формировать из mergerfile.

Что посоветуете?

Comment: приведите ваш код, где вы считываете и добавляйте в лист.. вы не храните считанные данные в переменной?  если да, то это дополнительный расход.

Comment: ArrayList имеет внутреннюю длину, при превышении половины которой список начнет пересобираться, выделяя внутри новый массив и копируя все данные. Указывая правильный capacity при создании ArrayList вы уже сэкономите кучу времени и памяти.

Comment: Соглашусь с комментатором выше - возможно будет оптимальней сначала определить длину массива(вов). Тут, судя по всему, представлен хороший способ сделать это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на этот вопрос меняется в зависимости от того, что следует делать с полученными массивами. Уточните, какие предполагаются расчеты над данными. Возможно не стоит считывать все строки из файлов, а достаточно их обрабатывать порциями. Например, в простейшем случае, можно посчитать среднее арифметическое суммируя значения из каждой строки и увеличивая счетчик строк (если значений очень много, то можно хранить в памяти промежуточные результаты суммирования, чтобы избежать переполнения).
Если же необходимо все-таки получить все данные в виде массива - то можно предварительно "пробежаться" по файлам и посчитать количество строк, и отталкиваясь от этой информации подготовить массив. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/453067/3955135) рассказали, как можно быстро посчитать строки.

Comment: для чего готовить массив? листы имеют такие ограничения, что ему не достичь с его задачей.

Comment: Готовить значение размера массива, для его создания. В любом случае, и с массивом и с листом упремся в ограничение по размеру. Думаю целесообразней было бы переложить всю работу по расчетам на плечи СУБД. Опять же - все зависит от того, что нужно посчитать.

Answer (score 1):

1. `ArrayList<Double[]> massivData = new ArrayList<Double[]>();`
   Сэкономит память, массив вместо объекта ArrayList.
   Читаете строку, бьёте на массив из строк, знаете количество элементов создаёте массив Double. Конвертируете из строк в дабл
2. Существуют библиотеки для экономии памяти коллекциями: FastUtils и Koloboke.

Answer (score 1):

1. Любые коллекции примитивных типов (например, чисел) в 4-5 раз быстрее релизованы в библиотеках типа Trove (TDoubleArrayList, см., например, https://habrahabr.ru/post/187234/) или упомянутых выше Koloboke (новая замена Trove) и FastUtils. Всё дело в конвертации из объектов Double в значения double и обратно (Autoboxing/Autounboxing).
2. Если заранее выделить память под 50000*100 элементов

   ```
   ArrayList<Double> massivData = new ArrayList<Double>(5000000*8);
   ```

   всё уже будет значительно быстрее - экономим на перевыделении памяти при росте списка (уже замечено выше: [Использование arraylist при больших объемах данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577240/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-arraylist-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/578145#comment765054_577240) )
3. `ArrayList<double[]>` будет быстрее `ArrayList<Double[]>` и тем более быстрее `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>()`.  Массив `double[]` уже является ссылочным типом, так что поддерживается коллекциями, менять число элементов в строке и хранить null вероятнее всего не требуется.
4. Считывать все файлы в один список значительно быстрее, чем объединять. Если непремено нужно быстрое объединение, придётся использовать самодельные или сторонние связанные списки. Стандартный `LinkedList<double[]>` склеивается долго, `ArrayList` тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятен изначальный вопрос.
в Java ArrayList ограничен только объемом физической памяти.

```
    List<Double> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(1d);
    data.add(2d);
    ....
    data.add(99999999d);
```

Посему предлогаю:
1) не считывать всю информацию со всех фалов сразу - может выйти накладно по ресурсам
2) Считали данные, проверили данные, сохранили в результирующую структуру. Повторили процедуру со следующим файлом.

Comment: Имелось ввиду, что arrayList менее эффективный, чем обычный статичный массив. Вот к примеру код наглядно показывающий:

Comment: К примеру: для заполнения arraylist из 200000 строк и 25 столбцов потребовалось 1919 мс. для заполнения такого же статичного массива 32. Также загрузка оперативной памяти слишком разная в этих случаях. Думаю делать промежуточные расчеты пускай каждых 10-20 файлов. потом из этих файлов уже сформировать массив

Comment: Все таки очень хотелось бы увидеть пример Вашего кода.

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте использовать `LinkedList`, у него нет ограничения, как у ArrayList (Integer.MAX_VALUE - максимальное значение).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767979/how-many-data-a-list-can-hold-at-the-maximum

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: тут пока и близко к двум миллиардам не подобрались